# Python - Dataframe contains column names that need to be dropped in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

The first dataframe is simply one column where each row is a column name in the 2nd dataframe.  This dataframe only contains a subset of all the columns.

What I want to do is remove the columns in the 2nd dataframe that are referenced in the smaller one.  I've written a loop that does that, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do so, as I need to remove about 5,000 columns.

Here's my code that accomplishes this task:

```
for i in to_remove['column_name']:
    df = df.drop(i, axis=1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cols': ['col1', 'col2']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['a', 'b'], 
                    'col2': ['a', 'b'], 
                    'col3': ['a', 'b'], 
                    'col4': ['a', 'b']})
```

Such that

```
>>> df
    cols
0   col1
1   col2

>>> df2
    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   a       a       a       a
1   b       b       b       b
```

#### Option1: `isin`+ `~`

You can use `isin`+ unary opearator `~`

```
df2.loc[:, ~df2.columns.isin(df.cols)]

    col3    col4
0   a       a
1   b       b
```

#### Option2: `drop`+`axis=1`

```
df2.drop(df.cols, axis=1) # same as df2.drop(columns=df.cols)

    col3    col4
0   a       a
1   b       b
```

These commands *return* a new `df`. So do not forget to assign the result back to a variable (e.g. `df2 = df2.drop(df.cols, axis=1)`)

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are looking for but the following should work:

```
df_new = df.drop(columns=to_remove['column_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df.drop(to_remove.column_name, axis=1, inplace=True)
```